# Сокращение массива - PHP

Tags: ssp.class.php

Есть такой массив:

```
$arr = [[0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,1,1,1][0,0,1,1,1][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,1,1,1][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,0,0,1][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,1][0,0,1,0,0][1,1,1,1,1][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Проверяем каждый элемент массива, если встречаем 1, то записываем этот элемент в новый массив. Если в элементе не встречается 0, то нужно остановить запись и продолжить поиски. В итоге должен получится такой массив:

```
[[[0,0,0,1,1][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,1,1,1][0,0,1,1,1]],[[0,0,1,1,1][0,0,0,1,1][0,0,0,0,1][0,0,0,1,1]],[[0,0,0,0,1][0,0,1,0,0][1,1,1,1,1]]]
```

Пробую сделать так

```
for ($n = 0; $n <= 5; $n++) { //знаю, что должно быть около 6 массивов
    for ($a = 0; $a <= count($arr); $a++) {
         if(@array_sum($arr[$a]) > 0) {
            $array_symbols[$n][] = $arr[$a];
        }else{
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 0;
$array_symbols = []; // массив результатов
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if(array_sum($item) > 0) {
        $array_symbols[$index][] = $item;
    } elseif ($array_symbols) { // отбрасываем первые пустые результаты
        $index++;
    }
}
```

Так?